# Contract to Contract Execution Visiblity

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Contract A

Contract B

Sender ---> Contract A ---> Request Information ----> Contract B

Action Complete <--- Contract A <--- Return Information <---- Contract B

Is the returned information visible anywhere? I am not asking about caller data or the original sender, I am saying that the contract question asked of Contract B, can it be linked to the original caller because of the requested action of Contract A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If contract A or B does not emit the event with information, the return information cannot be seen. The original caller can be got by `tx.origin`.